# How to get Jersey to enforce BAD REQUEST response on invalid data?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I currently have a Jersey resource that takes a boolean as a parameter in the following form:

```
public Response getUserInfo(
        @PathParam("userID") final long userID,
        @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("details") final boolean includeUserDetails) {
  // ...
}
```

While the service itself works fine, I noticed that Jersey uses `Boolean.valueOf` to convert input variables to boolean. This means everything that is not `"true"` is mapped to `false`.

Is there any way to tell Jersey to automatically respond with a `BAD REQUEST` if the user enters an invalid value (like "stopid" instead of "false")?

I know I can just manually convert that, but since that is not the only case and place, I'd prefere a global and automated way to reject everything that obviously does not match the input with a bad request, including i.E. numbers.

Comment: Have you considered a [`ParamConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverter.html) throwing a [`BadRequestException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html)?

Comment: Or, simpler, define a `IncludeUserDetails` class with a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single `String` argument, throwing a [`BadRequestException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html)  It should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is that there are many different positions in the code where this happens, and a solution like a specific class means I would have to code like 100 classes just to throw bad requeste exceptions, which is honestly too much.

Comment: Specifically for the boolean case, I would use the converter, because of the way Jersey handles the conversion. For other cases, you might want to look into [bean validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)